# JSON response_body generated by rspec_api_documentation gem is empty (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-api-documentation

I've successfully used `rspec_api_documentation` gem to generate docs for some other resources in an application.

But when I do the same for a new resource, the JSON file's `response_body` is empty (though the rest of the JSON exists). And I'm unsure why this is happening.

**response_body in generated JSON:**

```
"response_body": "{\n  \"data\": {\n    \"notes\": [\n\n    ]\n  },\n  \"status\": 200,\n  \"message\": \"Ok\"\n}"
```

**Outputed API docs:**

```
{
  "data": {
    "notes": [

    ]
  },
  "status": 200,
  "message": "Ok"
}
```

**What I've done:**

- Tested the endpoint with a `curl` and can confirm it returns a full response (now I'm just trying to build the documentation)
- Created `note_factory.rb`
- Added `@notes = create_list(:note, 1,...)` in a `before(:all) do` block at beginning of `notes_spec.rb` (and printed to console to confirm it creates an object)

Also created below as the test.

```
get '/api/v1/notes' do

  example 'Return all notes' do
    explanation 'Return all notes within an account.'

    set_jwt_auth_headers(@api_reader)

    do_request

    expect(status).to eq 200
  end
end
```

I'm confused what I might be missing that causes the JSON response related to `RAD` to be empty.

Does anyone have any ideas what might cause this?

Comment: I have the same issue... hitting a JSON API and getting a blank response_body. Did you figure out what was going wrong?